# .Gsub and .Scan Rails. Regex deciphering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Why does this happen:

```
filename
=> "/Users/user/Desktop/work/arthouse/digitization/in-process/cat.jpg"
[4] pry(DigitizedView)> filename.gsub(/.*\//,'')
=> "cat.jpg"
```

What is the regex in the first argument of `gsub`? I know the `.*` is any number of any characters... but what is the backslash? Why does it delete everything except the `cat.jpg` part?

Also,

```
"cat.jpg".scan(/(\w+)-(\d+)([a-z]?)/)
=> []
```

What is that code doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let us examine what this first argument for the `gsub` method, `/.*\//` means.

the first and last slashes `/.../` denotes that we are dealing with a regex here, not string.

There are two parts to this regex. `.*` and `\/`.

`.*` says that grep any characters, including empty character.

`\/` says that grep a string with a slash, `/`.

This regex would catch,

`['/', 'Users/', 'user/', 'Desktop/', 'work/', 'arthouse/', 'digitization/', 'in-process/']`

All these strings are now replaced with ''.

Except `cat.jpg` which doesn't have the slash at the end.

Hope that explanation helps.

- edit

In the second part, `/(\w+)-(\d+)([a-z]?)/`

`(\w+)`: grep a group of word characters (includes numbers)
`-`: grep for a dash
`(\d+)`: grep a group of numeric digits
`([a-z]?)`: grep for nil char or a single char.

cat.jpg doesn't fit into this regex in many ways. No dash, `.` in the string. etc.

Therefore, `scan` will return an empty array.

Comment: How about the second part?

Comment: `grep` is a method that matches strings with the first argument, and replaces the matched strings with the second argument. So the second argument `''` will basically make the all the matched strings into empty char.

Comment: I mean the scan part?

Comment: See my updated response

Comment: how could someone downvote your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Regexp `/.*\//` matches zero or more characters terminated by a forward slash. The `String#gsub` method replaces all substrings matching the pattern with the replacement value, in this case `''`.

So in this  case, the pattern matches the following substrings: `'/'`, `'Users/'`, `'user/'`, `'Desktop/'`, `'work/'`, `'arthouse/'`, `'digitization/'`, and `'in-process/'`. It replaces each of these with a blank string. It does not match the remaining substring, `cat.jpg`, because that substring doesn't terminate with a `'/'`. So `'cat.jpg'` is all that remains.